# Reduce font-awesome size with node.js + express.js website

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, font-awesome

I am working on a website based on node.js + express.js, using font-awesome as icon technique.

Font-awesome is locally hosted, and JS file [font-awesome.js] is 1.2 mb, although we are using 10-15 icons only. Want to reduce that size.

**Option I understand,**

If I open JS file, there is an array named icons, listing SVG content for all icons. So, I can delete all but required ones.
However, obvious issue with this option is that if I want to use another icon in future, I need edit it again.
[image]

**Option I don't understand,**

There exists an [svc-javascript-core] package (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-javascript-core), that allows creating required subset. It also mentions that if you are not using any tool doing tree-shaking (I'm not), you can use deep-imports (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/other/tree-shaking).

However, I don't understand,

- Would it result in creating a new JS file containing only the subset (or can I code that myself?)
- Would that change the way I use font-awesome in my pages?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the reason they sell the "kits", tailored to your needs (only packaging the icons you need). You'd need the icons on the client side, so I don't believe the node.js and express tags are relevant here. What are you using on the client side? Plain html + js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Subsetter App for Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/other-topics/subsetter), which let you choose only the icons you're using in your website.

To answer your other question: no, this would not change the way you're using Font Awesome. Except for having to update your subset when you need new icons.